# Problem While Calculating Correlation Coefficient in R

Tags: r, excel

I was trying to calculate correlation coefficient among some variables in R. The problem here is that R can read the data but can't calculate the correlation coefficient properly as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: R Code and Result]

Previously I was able to calculate correlation coefficient in R from other excel file data with the same code as shown in the figure. What's the problem here?

Comment: It was better providing code as a text, not an image.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the kind advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although data/code you provide is an image, I think I can give a solution for this case.

To state the reason of problem first, the reason your correlation matrix looks weird is `complete.obs` do the same work with `na.omit` and in your `data_cor`, there only two row exists that does not have `NA` in every variable.

For example, let's define data `dummy` as below and look at result.

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  N0 = rnorm(10),
  N1 = runif(10),
  N2 = c(.3,.4,rep(NA,8)),
  N3 = rchisq(10,3)
)
dummy

            N0         N1  N2       N3
1  -1.38246690 0.38116217 0.3 5.144132
2   0.77977538 0.06383890 0.4 3.195502
3  -1.08709820 0.28024669  NA 3.890352
4   0.34685457 0.71857164  NA 2.816047
5  -1.58245449 0.39671123  NA 5.136402
6  -0.38614131 0.02491107  NA 3.103611
7  -1.38644384 0.86949460  NA 4.255433
8  -0.87290110 0.39692126  NA 1.454483
9   0.01181121 0.31394631  NA 2.802918
10 -0.97159797 0.05254728  NA 1.458610

cor(dummy, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
   N0 N1 N2 N3
N0  1 -1  1 -1
N1 -1  1 -1  1
N2  1 -1  1 -1
N3 -1  1 -1  1

cor(na.omit(dummy))
   N0 N1 N2 N3
N0  1 -1  1 -1
N1 -1  1 -1  1
N2  1 -1  1 -1
N3 -1  1 -1  1
```

As you know about how correlation coefficients calculated, if there only two samples per variable exists, (`x1,x2` v.s. `y1,y2`) is `1` or `-1`(suppose `x1 != x2` and `y1 != y2`).

So, in this case, if your purpose is to use a sample that has complete observation, that result might correct.

It must be `1` or `-1` against `N4` but if you need proper correlation coefficients between others, try using `pairwise.complete.obs` argument for `use =`.

```
cor(dummy, method = "pearson", use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

           N0         N1 N2         N3
N0  1.0000000 -0.2408998  1 -0.4259661
N1 -0.2408998  1.0000000 -1  0.3043064
N2  1.0000000 -1.0000000  1 -1.0000000
N3 -0.4259661  0.3043064 -1  1.0000000
```

In this case, this will give proper result for other variables.

```
cor(dummy[,-3])

           N0         N1         N3
N0  1.0000000 -0.2408998 -0.4259661
N1 -0.2408998  1.0000000  0.3043064
N3 -0.4259661  0.3043064  1.0000000
```

Comment: Yes. It was regarding the NA value. Now it works. Thanks.